# Arduino: Parsing not showing the list of string parsed

Tags: string, parsing, arduino, at-command

i am trying to parse a list of messages that is converted to a single line of string with a delimiter of `'*'` for each sms, now whenever i pass only 1 sms it prints the desired output, but when i pass more than 1 sms it will not parse or split each message from the converted single line of string

this is what the converted single line of string looks like

```
+CMGL: 14,REC UNREAD,+639321576684,Ralph Manzano,16/05/04,02:27:03+32,You$*+CMGL: 15,REC UNREAD,+639321576684,Ralph Manzano,16/05/04,02:27:08+32,There$*+CMGL: 16,REC UNREAD,+639321576684,Ralph Manzano,16/05/04,02:26:59+32,Hey$*+CMGL: 17,REC UNREAD,+639321576684,Ralph Manzano,16/05/04,02:35:31+32,Hi$*>
```

this is actually a response of an AT command but as you can see each sms is divided by `'*'` and has an `'>'` as and indicator of an end of the line. this is the code that i use to parse this converted single line of string.

```
void parse_list(String list) {
  Serial.println("Parsing...");
  delay(1000);

  String sms1 = "";
  String sms2 = "";
  String sms3 = "";
  String sms4 = "";

  char charData, charData2;
  int index = 0, index2 = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
    charData = list.charAt(i);

    if (charData == '*') {
      index++;

    }
    else if (charData == '>') {
      index = 0;
    }
    else {
      SMSlist[index] += charData;
    }

  }


  sms1 = SMSlist[0];
  sms2 = SMSlist[1];
  sms3 = SMSlist[2];
  sms4 = SMSlist[3];

  Serial.println(sms1);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(sms2);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(sms3);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(sms4);
  delay(1000);

  clear_smslist();
}

void clear_smslist() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    SMSlist[i] = "";
  }
}
```

what seems to be wrong in my code? thank a lot for the help

Comment: Arduino is not C and not exactly C++.

Comment: And this is no debugging service. See [ask].

Comment: So, how exactly it does misbehave? Few parts definitely looks fishy. For example, are You sure that `SMSlist[index] += charData;` does exactly what You need?